# How to override valueOf() by a correct type, that is not a primitive one?

Tags: javascript

Suppose that I need to override the internal valueOf() by Array type...

As [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) the *valueOf()* method returns the primitive value of the specified object... So, I suppose that we can set the primitive value to any datatype... Can we? or there are restrictions?

Here the same example of the link, changing only the return and the test:

```
function MyNumberType(n) {
  this.number = n;
}
MyNumberType.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return [123,this.number];
};

const object1 = new MyNumberType(4);    
console.log(object1 +  [1,1]); // expected output: 123,41,1
```

Comment: When how will you access the actual object?

Comment: `valueOf() method returns the primitive value of the specified object` but an Array `return [123,this.number]` is no primitive

Comment: Hi @Thomas, make sense, there are only [six data types that are primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)... Delete this question?

Comment: oops, there are a good answer:  **is not** an Array solution but solve a lot of layout and debug problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Many operators and functions in JavaScript expect their arguments to have certain types. If they don’t, they are coerced (converted) to those types. Coercing an object to a primitive type is a two-step process: First, the object is converted to a primitive. Then, if necessary, the primitive is converted to the correct type. Two methods are used to convert an object to a primitive: valueOf() toString() <sup>1</sup>

Let's see what happens when you multiply two objects:

```js
function Foo() {
}

// valueOf returns an object which is not a primitive
Foo.prototype.valueOf = () => {
  console.log('converting to primitive');
  return {};
};

// valueOf returns an object which is not a primitive
Foo.prototype.toString = () => {
  console.log('converting to string');
  return 42;
};

const foo1 = new Foo();
const foo2 = new Foo();

console.log(foo1 * foo2);
```

As you can see, `valueOf()` is called first to convert an object to its primitive representation. However an object isn't a primitive, therefore `toString()` is called next.

The issue with your code is that, as @Thomas pointed out, `valueOf()` doesn't return a primitive value. Therefore `toString()` is called which returns the standard `[object Object]` unless you override it:

```js
function MyNumberType(n) {
  this.number = n;
}

MyNumberType.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  // force `toString()` to be called
  console.log('converting to primitive');
  return {};
};

MyNumberType.prototype.toString = function() {
  console.log('converting to string');
  return `123,${this.number}`;
};

const object1 = new MyNumberType(4);    
console.log(object1 +  [1,1]); // expected output: 123,41,1
```

**References**

1. http://2ality.com/2012/11/coercing-objects.html